# How to get HP Pavilion dv6 6155-tx supportable drivers for windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, laptop, drivers

I have HP Pavilion dv6 6155tx Laptop. Windows 7 is pre-installed in it. I want to install windows 8 on it. But HP does not provide windows 8 drivers for this laptop. I have tried to install windows 7 drivers on windows 8. But some drivers(e.g. graphics, etc) cause system crash. So, is there any way that how can I get windows 8 drivers for my laptop.

Comment: I've had quite a few HP Pavilion laptops for the past 10 years, as their high-end stuff is generally of good quality if handled properly. However, one thing I've learnt is that they do like to use hardware with very limited amount of drivers. I tried to downgrade from Vista to 7, and I eventually gave up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the hardware is too old it may not have available drivers for Windows 8.

Anyways, you can still search the manufacturer site for compatible drivers, you are likely to find more info in there. I have a HP laptop (DV6 as well), and I remember when I installed Windows 8 I got the drivers from AMD, Realtek ... sites, and they worked perfectly.

If you need to identify which drivers are best for you, enter device manager in "my computer", right click your driver and check the Device/Vendor combination. Google it and download the latest version and you should be fine.